# I just want to call numbers I find on the internet!

Tags: chrome-for-android, google-hangouts, phone-app

When I click on a phone number in Chrome on the internet it prompts me to download Hangouts. I just want to call it with the default Samsung dialer not Hangouts! How do I do this?

Comment: What prevents you from simply typing the number by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the default application has been changed from "dialer" to "hangouts" - so when you press a phone number, it's calling to the default handler for that thing... which is the phone number.

So, look in your phone's settings for default apps and see what's selected for the dialer call as it should now be hangouts (so just look for hangouts in there and if you find it, click on it to change it - maybe, depends on your phone).

Good luck!